# How to fetch data from sqlite database and show it in a form view by using id in android

Tags: android

I am creating a small android application in which it will display calendar by clicking on date we will get a layout which has list views and a button by clicking on button we will get a form view the filled details will be displayed in the list view which is in second layout data will be fetched to list view by custom cursor adapter.**Now my question is by clicking on list view i should get the filled form view with the details in that row in database in read only mode** can any one help me how to fetch the data from sqlite database and display it in form view.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to create a method like-fetchData(int id) which get details from SQLite database by id.
And call it in listview.OnItemCLickListner(), and in listview.OnItemClickListner() method you should get the id or number of row on which user clicked and pass it into the Sqlite method fetchData(id);

I hope it will helpful.